# Select rows when a value appears multiple times

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table like this one:

```
+------+------+
|  ID  | Cust |
+------+------+
|   1  |  A   |
|   1  |  A   |
|   1  |  B   |
|   1  |  B   |
|   2  |  A   |
|   2  |  A   |
|   2  |  A   |
|   2  |  B   |
|   3  |  A   |
|   3  |  B   |
|   3  |  B   |
+------+------+
```

I would like to get the IDs that have at least two times A and two times B. So in my example, the query should return only the ID 1,

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: I prefer using Oracle

Comment: In the absence of a PK, you don't really have a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use two levels of aggregation:

```
select id
from (select id, cust, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      where cust in ('A', 'B')
      group by id, cust
     ) ic
group by id
having count(*) = 2 and  -- both customers are in the result set
       min(cnt) >= 2     -- and there are at least two instances
```

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL:

```
SELECT id
FROM test
GROUP BY id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(cust ORDER BY cust SEPARATOR '') LIKE '%aa%bb%'
```

In Oracle

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT id, LISTAGG(cust, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cust) custs
              FROM test
              GROUP BY id )
SELECT id
FROM cte
WHERE custs LIKE '%aa%bb%'
```

Comment: PS. For strictly "at least two times A and two times B" `LIKE '%AABB%'` is enough. Symbols are adjacent in ASCII so `%` in the middle of the pattern is excess.

Answer (score 1):

This is one option; lines #1 - 13 represent sample data. Query you might be interested in begins at line #14.

```
SQL> with test (id, cust) as
  2    (select 1, 'a' from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'a' from dual union all
  4     select 1, 'b' from dual union all
  5     select 1, 'b' from dual union all
  6     select 2, 'a' from dual union all
  7     select 2, 'a' from dual union all
  8     select 2, 'a' from dual union all
  9     select 2, 'b' from dual union all
 10     select 3, 'a' from dual union all
 11     select 3, 'b' from dual union all
 12     select 3, 'b' from dual
 13    )
 14  select id
 15  from (select
 16          id,
 17          sum(case when cust = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) suma,
 18          sum(case when cust = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) sumb
 19        from test
 20        group by id
 21       )
 22  where suma = 2
 23    and sumb = 2;

        ID
----------
         1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by and having for the relevant Cust ('A' , 'B')
And query twice (I chose to use with to avoid multiple selects and to cache it)

```
with more_than_2 as 
(
    select Id, Cust, count(*) c
    from tab
    where Cust in ('A', 'B')
    group by Id, Cust
    having count(*) >= 2
)
select *
from tab
where exists ( select 1 from more_than_2 where more_than_2.Id = tab.Id and more_than_2.Cust = 'A')
and exists ( select 1 from more_than_2 where more_than_2.Id = tab.Id and more_than_2.Cust = 'B')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a perfect candidate for match_recognize. Here you go:

```
select id_ as id from t
match_recognize
(
    order by id, cust
    measures id as id_
    pattern (A {2, } B {2, })
    define  A as cust = 'A',
            B as cust = 'B'
)
```

Output:

[image]

Regards,
Ranagal